# Chromecast button is not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, video, chromecast

I am trying to implement video casting to Chromecast and found some packages in flutter which are old and no updates. I tried some packages, but the Chromecast button is not working.
Please help me if you have any experience. Thank you.
Also, please recommend me a good package for video casting to Chromecast for flutter.

I have tried flutter_cast_video package in pub dev, but the Chromecast button is just grey out and is never clickable. I followed the instruction exactly how it is described but not sure why it is not working.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cast_video

Comment: I'm going through the same problem. It was working normally in my project, but recently, it stopped working. On Android the button is grayed out, on iOS the button works, however, it does not find devices. If anyone has any information regarding this issue, please share with us.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this. Seems like a popular one with 17 stars and repo has been updated recently.

https://github.com/gianlucaparadise/flutter_cast_framework

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks cool but It doesn't have a seek function which I definitely requires.

Comment: Check this link
https://github.com/gianlucaparadise/flutter_cast_framework/issues/5